# Approximate nearest neighbors search returns too few results

Tags: yql, vespa

I have 1M records in my db with such schema:

```
schema embeddings {
  document embeddings {
    field id type int {}
    field text_embedding type tensor<double>(d0[960]) {
      indexing: attribute | index
      attribute {
        distance-metric: euclidean
      }
      index {
          hnsw {
              max-links-per-node: 16
              neighbors-to-explore-at-insert: 100
          }
      }
    }
  }

  rank-profile closeness {
    num-threads-per-search:1
    inputs {
      query(query_embedding) tensor<double>(d0[960])
    }
    first-phase {
      expression: closeness(field, text_embedding)
    }
  }
}
```

My query for finding the nearest neighbors looks like this:

```
body = {
    'yql': 'select * from embeddings where ({approximate:true, targetHits:100} nearestNeighbor(text_embedding, query_embedding));',
    "hits":100,
    'input': {
        'query(query_embedding)': [...],
    },
    "ranking": {
        "profile": "closeness",
        "softtimeout": {
            "enable": false
        }
    }
}
```

For some reasons, for certain vectors the number of results is smaller, than `targetHits`. Changing timeouts does not help.

Here is coverage section from the response:

```
"id": "toplevel",
"relevance": 1.0,
"fields": {
    "totalCount": 39
},
"coverage": {
    "coverage": 100,
    "documents": 1000000,
    "full": true,
    "nodes": 1,
    "results": 1,
    "resultsFull": 1
},
```

Is there any way to receive exactly (or at least not less than) `targetHits` results (obviously there are enough results, since the closeness can be calculated for any other vector in the db)?

Comment: "Changing timeouts does not help." Are you sure? Can you check the coverage section in the result and include the coverage information of an incomplete result?

Comment: @Jon Added the coverage section

Answer (score 1):

When you ask for `targetHits:100`, Vespa will expose that to the `first-phase` ranking phase, per content node. If it does not, then we would be very interested in how to reproduce. That is best done by creating a issue over at [github vespa-engine/vespa](https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/issues). There is also support for dropping hits in `first-phase` ranking using `rank-score-drop-limit`, which can reduce the result set and `totalCount`. This does not seem to be enabled here.

The `hits` parameter (or `limit` in YQL) controls how many hits are returned in the response.

Vespa's default timeout is 500ms, and if your system is heavily overloaded (or using exact search with `approximate:false`), you might see [soft-timeouts](https://docs.vespa.ai/en/graceful-degradation.html) where Vespa returns a partial result. This situation is reflected in the returned result `coverage` element.

Comment: edited the question - disabled soft timeout, the result is the same

Comment: Then we are interested in how to reproduce this; it's not expected behavior from how you describe your setup. Make sure that you are on a recent Vespa 8 version.